# Command working in bash terminal but not in Python subprocess.Popen(); getting a 'paths must precede expression: `%p' error

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to find the location of the file that has been most recently modified. In bash, you can do this through

```
 find /media/tiwa/usb/ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2) | sort -k1,1nr | head -1`
```

Indeed, on my system, this returns

```
1527379702.1060795850 /media/tiwa/usb/hi.txt
```

I intend to take the output of this command (within Python), split it on the first space, and parse the file path (yes, I could use `awk`, but the same errors get thrown regardless). So I did

```
import subprocess
bashCommand = "find /media/tiwa/usb/ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2) | sort -k1,1nr | head -1"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

but this prints out

```
find: paths must precede expression: `%p'
```

Escaping the backslashes doesn't appear to help either.

What is causing this issue, and how do I solve it?

Comment: You do realize that you're splitting the string, right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was under the impression that for subprocess.Popen(), you need to send an array of arguments as opposed to a string. **edit:** I just tried running it  without the `.split()`, and now I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: In this case, since you are using shell features (piping), you want the string unchanged and set `shell=True`.

Comment: @tdelaney If I understand you correctly, I should be doing `process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`? This gives me a `/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected` error. On the other hand, splitting the string along with `shell=True` causes an execution of simply `find` in the cwd.

Comment: Its the right basic plan but you may have escape problems with the backslashes. Try `bashCommand = r"find ..."` or change them to `\\\` .

Comment: @tdelaney Now I get `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: Instead of invoking a shell and hoping to get the escaping and output parsed correctly have you considered a pure python solution using `os.walk` or similar?

Comment: I took out `2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2)` and it seemed to work. I'm not sure what the problem is with a subshell.  You could filter the error on the python side.

Comment: @tdelaney Yep, that works on my side too. Thanks!

Comment: Adding `shell=True` (and not splitting the command) runs it with the shell /bin/sh, but the `>( )` construct (process substitution) is a bash-only feature, not supported by /bin/sh. Adding `executable="/bin/sh"` might solve this, but really I have to go with @EricRenouf and suggest tossing the shell mess and doing it directly in python.

Comment: `executable="/bin/bash"` , that is

Comment: @thatotherguy D'oh! Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an entire shell command line, not just a single command plus its arguments, which means you need to use the `shell=True` option instead of (erroneously) splitting the string into multiple strings. (Python string splitting is not equivalent to the shell's word splitting, which is much more involved and complicated.) Further, since your command line contains `bash`-specific features, you need to tell `Popen` to use `/bin/bash` explicitly, rather than the default `/bin/sh`.

```
import subprocess
bashCommand = "find /media/tiwa/usb/ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2) | sort -k1,1nr | head -1"
path_to_bash = "/bin/bash"  # or whatever is appropriate
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           shell=True,
                           executable=path_to_bash)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

(It would, however, be simpler and more robust to use `os.walk()` to get each file, and use `os.stat()` to get the modification time of each relevant file, and only keep the newest file found so far until you have examined every file.

```
import os
newest = (0, "")
for (dir, subdirs, fname) in os.walk("/media/tiwa/usb"):
    if fname.startswith(".") or not os.path.isfile(fname):
        continue
    mtime = os.stat(fname).st_mtime
    if mtime > newest[0]:
        newest = (mtime, fname)
```

Or perhaps

```
def names_and_times(d):
    for (_, _, fname) in os.walk(d):
        if fname.startswith(".") or not os.path.isfile(fname):
            continue
        yield (os.stat(fname).st_mtime), fname)

newest = max(names_and_times("/media/tiwa/usb"))
```

)

Keep in mind that any of the preceding approaches will only return *one* file with the newest modification time.